# Jasmine tests with no expect() will succeed

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We're using [jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) for our testing environment. When implementing a test, a common mistake seems to be to first set up all the preconditions of the test and then to forget the actual call to expect. Unfortunately, such a test will always succeed; you don't see the test is actually faulty.

In my opinion, a test that does not expect anything should always fail. Is there a way to tell jasmine to adopt this behaviour? If not, is there another way how to make sure all my tests actually expect something?

Comment: That's why you need your test to fail first. :)

Comment: Sure thing. But if you're in a hurry, this can happen quite easily.

Comment: QUnit has this feature. Not sure if jasmine or mocha does.

Comment: According to https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1221 there should be a warning, but I couldn't find it. I'm also looking for that feature.

Answer (score 1):

From [Jasmine's documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/pages/faq.html#no-assertions) (emphasis mine):

> By default, Jasmine doesn’t require specs to contain any expectations.
> You can enable that behavior by **setting the *failSpecWithNoExpectations*
> option to *true***:
>
> - If you’re using the standalone distribution, add it to the config object in lib/jasmine-/boot.js.
> - If you’re using the jasmine NPM package, add it to your config file (usually spec/support/jasmine.json).
> - If you’re using a third party tool that wraps jasmine-core, check that tool’s documentation for how to pass configuration options.
> - If you’re using jasmine-core directly, add it to the object that you pass to Env#configure.
>
> We don’t recommend relying on the failSpecWithNoExpectations option.
> All it ensures is that each spec has at least one expectation, not
> that the spec will actually fail for the right reason if the behavior
> it’s trying to verify doesn’t work. The only way to be sure that a
> spec is actually correct is to try it both ways and see that it passes
> when the code under test is working and fails in the intended way when
> the code under test is broken. Very few people can consistently write
> good specs without doing that, just like very few people can
> consistently deliver working non-test code without trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ESLint plugin [eslint-plugin-jasmine](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine) that can ensure that tests have at least one `expect()` call, and that those calls have a matcher.